# RuntimeError when running rails test: "Application has been already initialized."

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am somewhat new to rails. I have just develop is this new app and have not made many changes to the default configurations.

When running "rails test", I get the following RuntimeError:

```
    Running via Spring preloader in process 1447
    /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:351:in `initialize!': Application has been already initialized. (RuntimeError)
        from /Users/holth/Documents/Code/Rails/ocmp/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/Documents/Code/Rails/ocmp/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/Documents/code/rails/ocmp/test/controllers/buy_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:11:in `block in require_files'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `each'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:10:in `require_files'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:76:in `plugin_rails_init'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:80:in `block in init_plugins'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `each'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:78:in `init_plugins'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest.rb:129:in `run'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/test.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:95:in `test'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/Documents/Code/Rails/ocmp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Users/holth/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have tried modifying "config/environment.rb" to have:

```
    Rails.application.initialize! unless Rails.env.test?
```

Rails test would begin but I would get error on all test.

```
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary found.
```

Here's my "database.yml":

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ocmp_development
  host: localhost

test:
  <<: *default
  database: ocmp_test
```

Here's my "test_helper.rb":

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Please help, many thanks.

Comment: What does your config/environment.rb look like?  What's in line 9, in particular?

Comment: It has "Rails.application.initialize!". I have tired "Rails.application.initialize! unless Rails.env.test?" but then I get this error: "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary found."

Comment: What do you have in your test_helper.rb?

Comment: since it's an ActiveRecord error, the issue is with connecting to the database. What's in your database.yml file?

Comment: Afolabi - I have included my "test_helper.rb" and "database.yml". I haven't change the default.